# fadeOut on scroll at pixel height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadeout

i'm trying to achieve a Scroll to Top button that fades in at a certain point on the page and fades out at a certain point...I have the fadeIn function working properly but can't seem to get the proper syntax for the click event fadeOut; it just disappears once you get to the top, instead of fading out if you're <= 675px. Any help is greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
</div>
<a href="#top" class="scrollToTop">BACK TO LOGIN</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 675) {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn(500);
        } else {        
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut(500);
        }

    });

    //Click event to scroll to top  
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop : 0
        }, 800);
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: I create a fiddle with your code and seems that it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/uowLcsb7/ check it and clear exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question isn't so clear but maybe you mean that when click on the scrollToTop button it doesn't disappear until the scroll reach to top of page, it's because when your animation function is running the `.scroll` can't runs so fast that disappear button when reach to 675px but you can fadeout button as soon as click on it using this code:

```
jQuery: $(document).ready(function() {
    var isClicked = false;
    $('.scrollToTop').css("display","none");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if (isClicked == false){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 675) {
                $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn(500);
            } else {
                $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut(500);
            }
        }
    });

    $('.scrollToTop').click(function() {
        isClicked = true;
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut(500);
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop : 0
        }, 800, function(){
            isClicked = false;
        });
    });
});
```

The `isClicked` variable is added to prevent blinking button (you can remove it to figure out what i'm saying).
Also i add this line:

```
$('.scrollToTop').css("display","none");
```

because it seems that you don't need a "Scroll To Top" button when page load for first time and you are on the top of page.

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uowLcsb7/2/)**

Comment: sorry for my poorly worded question! that does work however, if you don't click the "scroll to top" button and you manually scroll to the top, it hides behind the navbar once you get to the top...is there any way of fading this out even if the button isn't clicked?

Comment: I think figure out your mean now, when you scrollup it's hiding on 675px, maybe you scroll fast, scroll slower and you can see that it works fine, but i thing you have a navbar top of site that when you scrollup so fast, the button cover the navbar, the solution is not in JQuery code, you need to set a z-index:100 for navbar and a z-index:99 for scrolltotop button in CSS to solve this problem.

Comment: I update the "JSFiddle Demo" in the answer, please check that again specially CSS section and let me know if i understand your question correctly.